# Android: EditText temporarily cleared when SELECTED (not written)

Tags: android

is there a method by which an EditText can be 'temporarily' cleared when SELECTED?
In other words, I'd like to achieve these steps:

1) at the beginning it is present a hint

2) as soon as I select the EditText, it appears cleared, empty, with only the lightening cursor visible

3) **without clicking 'send'**, so whithout confirming the written text, I click on somewhere else in the activity

4) the intial hint will appears again

I tried using *android:hint*, but the text doesn't disappear when EditText is selected.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the hint text color transparent when EditText is focused and gray in normal state. Create a `text_color_hint.xml` file in `res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:color="#808080" />
</selector>
```

Then assign the `text_color_hint` to `android:textColorHint`. Your EditText should look something like this:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="HINT HERE"
        android:textColorHint="@drawable/text_color_hint"/>
```

To avoid the EditText being auto focused, you can:

1) Add  `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the **parent** layout of EditText, here I take LinearLayout as an example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

OR

2) Create a dummy LinearLayout which takes no space, add the above 2 elements to it, and put it **right before** the EditText:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="HINT HERE"
        android:textColorHint="@drawable/text_color_hint"/>
```

Comment: If I do this, the hint in the box disappear. It seems like the focus state is always set to "true".

Comment: @lorenzotosone Edited my answer to include how to avoid auto focus.

Comment: Problem fixed by using the dummy LinearLayout, thank you very much.